# Should copper fill zones be included for every layer?

Tags: pcb

I am working on a PCB but don't understand if I need a fill zone for each layer. I have a via which uses a B.CU layer. Do I need a copper fill zone for this too or is the copper fill zone for F.CU enough for both sides?

[image]

Comment: Well, if you wanted to be ultra-cheap, you could easily do that pcb with only 1 layer & no vias.  But it sounds to me that you're more interested in design considerations and theory.  Maybe check this out for starters: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySuUZEjARPY, and go down the rabbit hole from there.

Comment: yes it answers my question. thank you.